# I am trying to get youtube title from url using json file but i do not get any result and i also do not get any exception

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I am trying to get youtube title from url using json file but i do not get any result and i also do not get any exception. I try to toast exception in toast message is null / blank. Can any one help me please. my code is here...

```
String link = youtube url;
URL embededURL = null;
try {
    embededURL = new URL("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" + link + "&format=json");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    makeToast(e.getMessage());
}
try {
    title = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(embededURL)).getString("title");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    makeToast(e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    makeToast(e.getMessage());
}

makeToast(title);
```

Comment: What version of Apache Commons IO are you using? It appears that [`IOUtils.toString(URL)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString-java.net.URL-) has been deprecated since version 2.5. Here's a list of the latest releases: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since your question tag is `android-volley`, I'm going to give you an `android-volley` answer. However, there are a lot of libraries to look into that manage HTTP calls in a subjectively nicer way like OkHttp.

Now, the short answer to your question is your code is not even making a call to the internet.

Longer answer:

1. Add the [volley dependency](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) to your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    //... other dependencies
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

2. Put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml
3. Make the app call to the internet like below. I tweaked [the Android Volley simple example.](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#java)

```java
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
// sample of a URL-encoded url param, so you'll need to convert your link variable if you haven't already
String url = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DiwGFalTRHDA&format=json";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                String title = new JSONObject(response).getString("title");
                Toast.makeText(context, title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Hi bro i already used this but still if we toast the error like e.getMessage then it toast blank. How can i solve this

Comment: My advice is don’t use toast for error messages. If you’re pursuing Android development whether as a hobby or career get comfortable reading the logs. Toast something user-friendly even if it just says “An error has occurred”.

Comment: I posted working code on my sample, including a sample URL. You just have to paste it over your non-working code and I guarantee it will toast the title. After that, you have to tweak it to suit your needs.